# What are effective lifestyle modifications for gastritis?

Tags: gastroenterology, stomach, lifestyle

There is a question here on Health.SE [What are effective lifestyle modifications for people with gastric acid reflux?](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/3265/what-are-effective-lifestyle-modifications-for-people-with-gastric-acid-reflux)

I am curious of the recommended lifestyle modifications are different for gastritis (inflammation of the stomach)? What changes in lifestyle can help reduce the pain and/or reduce the inflammation?

Comment: Gastritis is a broad term: it can be acute or chronic, autoimmune or caused by H. pylori, etc. To get a helpful answer you may want to specify gastritis a bit more.

Answer (score 2):

To treat gastritis naturally there are some lifestyle changes you can do.
 1. For starters, stop smoking and limit drinking.
 2. Avoid trigger foods and eat smaller meals more frequently to avoid indigestion.
 3. Control stress.
 4. Limit the use of pain-relievers and anti-inflammatory medications.
 5. Consume licorice prior to eating a meal. 
 6. Ginger has been shown to be quite beneficial for the stomach, so it may also help with gastritis.
 7. Drink lots of water (at least eight glasses a day).
 8. Marshmallow may help aid in fighting nausea and vomiting.

Besides these you also want to follow a [gastritis-friendly diet](http://www.belmarrahealth.com/gastritis-diet-foods-to-eat-and-avoid-dietary-plan-and-recommendations/) and also be aware of the foods that can worsen your condition.

Foods you should limit or avoid.

- Hot cocoa and cola
- Whole milk and chocolate milk
- Peppermint and spearmint
- Tea Regular and decaf coffee
- Orange and grapefruit juices
- Black and red pepper
- Garlic powder

The foods you should eat with gastritis are also the foods that should always be included in any healthy eating diet. These are whole foods that provide nutrients and can support overall health. Some foods you should eat with gastritis are leafy greens, low-fat proteins, foods containing flavonoids like brightly colored fruits and vegetables, and foods rich in fiber.